# What would cause a PHP response to have some extra whitespace at the beginning?

Tags: php

I have identical code on my production and local *AMP servers.

I've created a webservice that returns JSON in the response.

However, on my production platform, when the service responds, I get an extra whitespace (a tab) at the beginning of my response. Even after removing the output for the JSON, there is a tab at the beginning of the file. If I `exit;` completely from the beginning of the script that creates the JSON response, the whitespace goes away. There isn't any other place that I can see that would add this extra whitespace, and it doesn't add it in my development sandbox.

Is there something I'm missing? Has anyone ever has this problem?

Here's some of the code I'm using:

```
require_once('includes/config.php');

function checkIfExists($parameterName) {
    if (!isset($_REQUEST[$parameterName])) {
        throw new AppException("Missing parameter '$parameterName'");
    }

    if (!$value = trim($_REQUEST[$parameterName])) {
        throw new AppException("Missing parameter '$parameterName'");
    }

    return $value;
}

try {
    //my try block, this is where i create an array and then echo out a json_encoded string
} catch (AppException $e) {
    //my catch block here
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: I can't post the entire code I'm using to the public but I've included a bit of it here. The point is that it's happening on one server but not another even though the code is identical. That leads me to believe it might be some sort of server configuration as opposed to code...but I'm not sure.

Comment: What are the two different servers, difference in OS?

Comment: OSX local server, Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64 bit production

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can't really accurately diagnose without seeing the code in its entirety, but check files for white space before the opening `<?php` tag, as that will be sent to the browser as well. I've had this happen a few times.

Comment: Ditto, probably whitespace before <?php tag

Comment: Also check *after* the closing ?> and inside *all included* files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip -- I've gone through all my files, checked beginning and end tags. No dice.

Comment: Actually -- my mistake. There was a file that was not version-controlled on the server which had a tab space after the closing `?>` tag. Case solved! Thanks guys!

Comment: Sweet! Glad you found the problem and squashed it!